# Redirect access to root dir

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to to redirect access to mysite.com/mydir/, to mysite.com/mydir/index.html

There is a .htaccess config file inside the mydir but it doesn't work as expected:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ index.html [L,R=301]
```

Now when I go to mysite.com/mydir/ , I am redirected to:

```
mysite.com/mydir/C:/wamp/www/mysite/index.html
```

and If use instead:

```
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,R=301]
```

I am redirected to

```
mysite.com/index.html
```

Only thing that works is:

```
Rewriterule ^$ /mydir/index.html [L,R=301]
```

but I don't want to hardcode mydir, because this .htaccess might be used in another directory. Could this be solved in a modular way?

Comment: Have you tried Rewriterule ^(.*)$ $1/index.html [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the following (`.htaccess` file stored in `mydir`):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mydir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mydir/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this since I don't have apache installed locally, but the problem is that you are not appending the group in the parens to the start of the url, if you try

```
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ $1/index.html [L,R=301]
```

Then it should will prepend what ever the characters at the start of your URL are i.e. mydir/ before index.html

Comment: Unfortunately this redirects to mysite.com/index.html, I tried also adding /, like this: /$1/index.html, but then it redirects to: mysite.com//index.html (2 slashesh)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put Rewriterule ^(.*)$ $1index.html [L,R=301].  I've tested this at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ - does this still not work?

Comment: I get redirects to mysite.com/mydir/C:/wamp/www/mysite/index.html
, which is weird, it might be something with WAMP configuration ?

Comment: Rewriterule ^/(.*)/$ localhost:8080/$1/index.html [L,R=301] (change 8080 to what ever port WAMP is running on)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ 
Rewriterule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}index.html [L,R=301]
```